# Intuition behind right-inverse of map from Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, metric-embeddings

The Johnson–Lindenstrauss lemma states that for every $n$-point subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and each $0<\varepsilon\le 1$, there is a linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^{O(\log(n)/\varepsilon^{-2})}$ such that
$$
(1-\varepsilon)\|x-y\| \le \|f(x)-f(y)\| \le (1+\varepsilon)\|x-y\|
\tag{1}
$$
for each pair of points $x,y\in X$.

Since $f$ is linear, and by construction, it has full row rank, it admits a linear right-inverse $g:\mathbb{R}^{O(\log(n)/\varepsilon^{-2})}\to \mathbb{R}^d$.  Set $Z:=f(X)$.  Furthermore, $(1)$ seems to imply that

- For each distinct pair of points $u,v\in Z$, we have $\|g(u)-g(v)\|\ge \dfrac{\min_{x,y;\,x\neq y}\|x-y\|}{(1+\varepsilon)}$
- $\operatorname{diam}(g(Z))\le \dfrac{\operatorname{diam}(X)}{1-\varepsilon}$

It is intuitive to me that the "inverse JL-map" $g$ expands the diameter of $Z$.  However, why does it contract the separation between distinct pairs of points in $Z$?

Comment: Which equation are you interpreting as contracting the separation between distinct pairs of points in $Z$? Inequality $a>b/(1+\epsilon)$ does not prevent $a=b$

Comment: @jlewk I misread you comment.  
This one
$\|f(x)-f(y)\|\le (1+\epsilon)\,\|x-y\|$
By a change of variable, since $f$ maps $X$ injectively onto $Z:=f(X)$, we have
$$
\frac1{1+\epsilon}\,\|u-v\| \le \|g(u)-g(v)\|
$$
for each $u,v\in Z$ (using the fact that for each $u\in Z$ there exists a unique $x\in X$ solving the following, $g(f(u))=x$)

Comment: This does not prevent the existence of points $u,v$ with $\|u-v\|>\|g(u)-g(v)\|$ or even $\|u-v\|>\sqrt{1+\epsilon}\|g(u)-g(v)\|$ which is the opposite of "contracting"

Comment: Ah, so basically a right inverse of Johnson and Lindenstrauss's map does not guarantee expansion of the pairwise distances between points?

Comment: For an example where equality holds, let $X$ be a set of collinear points.